# HTML a tag bookmark

Tags: html

I want the web page to start at the bottom of the screen on load of page from a link.
To do this i just put #bottom at the end of the url i want to load.

example:   www.something.com#bottom

This seems to work

I also want to be able to have a go to bottom of page button.

My code is:

```
<a href="#bottom">Go to bottom of page</a>
<a name="bottom"></a>
```

This will load the page at bottom but when i click on the go to bottom it reloads the page and loses all work that has been done. The go to bottom button will work fine with no reload now until the page reloads again. Then problem starts again.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: This should work. What is the URL of your page? How does it change when you click the link? Which browser are you using?

Comment: When you say 'the page loses all work' what does that mean -text inputs that have been filled out get cleared? Your code is fine, What else is on the page?

Comment: It seem to work fine in firefox just not in IE where i need it to work

Comment: The Url reads: www.something.com#bottom and reads the same thing after i click the go to bottom but reloads the page and all text inputs are cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.
I figured it out though this works

```
function ScrollTo(Aobj){
obj = document.getElementById(Aobj);
try{
    var objpos = ObjectPosition(obj);
}catch(e){}
try{
    scroll(0,objpos[1]);
}catch(e){}
try{
    window.scrollTo(0,objpos[1]);
}catch(e){}
```

}

```
function ObjectPosition(obj) {
var curleft = 0;
  var curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
              curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
              curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
  }
  return [curleft,curtop];
```

}

Got it from:
http://www.michaelapproved.com/articles/scroll-to-object-without-leaving-page/

```
<span style="color:#03F" onclick="ScrollTo('vsresponse')"><u>goto bottom</u></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I believe it should be `id`, not `name`.</strike>

```
<a href="#bottom">Go to bottom of page</a>
<a id="bottom"></a>
```

#### Edit

Nope, I was wrong. It shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do this with a link, because that inherently means that you have to reload the page.

- What you want to do is use [Javascript to scroll](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html).

Your `go to bottom button` could implement the solution described under the section titled 'Scroll Directly to a Particular Point'

Comment: So i figured it out. I am still using A tags to load to the bottom of the page. But to get the go to bottom of page working without reloading page i had to use:

Comment: function ScrollTo(Aobj){
 obj = document.getElementById(Aobj);
    try{
        var objpos = ObjectPosition(obj);
    }catch(e){}
    try{
        scroll(0,objpos[1]);
    }catch(e){}
    try{
        window.scrollTo(0,objpos[1]);
    }catch(e){}
}



function ObjectPosition(obj) {
    var curleft = 0;
      var curtop = 0;
      if (obj.offsetParent) {
            do {
                  curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
                  curtop += obj.offsetTop;
            } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
      }
      return [curleft,curtop];
}

Comment: um, can you plesae complete that sentence @user583576. NVM, you added while I was reading.

Comment: I see that you're relatively new to stackoverflow, and am going to try to say this as politely as possible without trying to sound like a reputation-whore... But if you're saying that my answer helped you, you should accept it (that means hat you click the green checkmark next to my answer), however if you feel otherwise you are in no way obligated to accept my answer. (just trying to teach you how the system works :) )